# Looping dynamic content on bootstrap4 rows

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I guess I have a simple question regarding using a for loop and indexes

I am trying to set up dynamic row and column using bootstrap4 and Python (Django).

I am looping through a list and What I am trying to do is to print each value in a column with a maximum of 3 columns.

I tried using :

```
  {% for member in project.team_id.members.all %}
      {% if loop.index % 3 == 0 %}
      <div class="row">
      {% endif%} 
...
...
...
...

  {% if (loop.index % 3 == 0 or loop.last) %}
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
```

but it does not work.. 
Could you help me to figure it out please ? 
Thx you ;)

Comment: Hi Clément, I tired to use forloop.counter but I always get the error that forloop is not defined

Comment: Are you sure you are not using the `forloop` tag **outside** of your `{% for %}` loop ?

Comment: I used it that way :
{% for member in project.team_id.members.all %}
      {% if forloop.counter % 3 == 0 %}
      <div class="row">
      {% endif%}